# jQuery to not perform function on child click but perform on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a FAQ and I make a list of block and when 
< li> is clicked it's child  expands and when again < li> is clicked will close . Everything is working fine but when I also click on  it still closing it.

I want only when box was clicked is clicked it will open his child "reveal" only and when it click again, it will hide "reveal"

My jQuery is:

```
$(".toggle").click(function(){
     $(this).find('.reveal').addClass('open').slideToggle();
 return false;
  });
```

I been 1 hour, I searched stackflow, and one said to use "return false;"; but it doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?
and here's the demo at the list of boxes: 
[demo](http://stuffhowto.com/alternative/top-web-hosting-services-2017)

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).find('.reveal').addClass('open').slideToggle();

});
```

```css
ol {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(61, 70, 77, 0.1);
}

ol li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9eaec
}

ol li .shown {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

ol li .shown * {
  float: left;
  line-height: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

ol li .number {
  width: 8%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

ol li .number span {
  background-color: #F29898;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 0px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 15px 8px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  top: 25px;
  left: -15px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
}

ol li .name {
  width: 52%;
  line-height: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
}

.detailed ol li .name {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

ol li .name span {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #F29898;
}

ol li .rating {
  width: 20%;
}

ol li .rating span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #F29898;
  opacity: .8;
}

ol li .goto {
  width: 20%;
}

ol li .goto .btn {
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 24px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

ol li .reveal {
  display: none;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li class="toggle">
    <div class="shown">
      <div class="number">
        <span>4</span>
      </div>
      <div class="name">
        <span>GoDaddy</span>
      </div>
      <div class="rating">
        <span>8.5/10</span>
      </div>
      <div class="goto">
        <a class="btn">Visit</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reveal" id="four-reveal">
      <p>We personally love GoDaddy but <u>their are many mix reviews about the company hosting services</u>. Some love them, some don't. But GoDaddy doesn't get so big by accident, they have more than 14 million customers. We personally host our clients
        websites on GoDaddy;</p>
      <p>GoDaddy shared hosting plan offers <b>uptime of 99.9% guarantee</b>, with <b>24/7 support via phone and email or Fourm</b>; and We can tell you one thing sure, their <b>Support is the best</b>. </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Please create working code example here.

Comment: @Dinesh I added the working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of firing an event on `li`, try fire it on `shown`. check the below code:

```js
$(".toggle .shown").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.reveal').addClass('open').slideToggle();

});
```

```css
ol {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(61, 70, 77, 0.1);
}

ol li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9eaec
}

ol li .shown {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}

ol li .shown * {
  float: left;
  line-height: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

ol li .number {
  width: 8%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

ol li .number span {
  background-color: #F29898;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 0px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 15px 8px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  top: 25px;
  left: -15px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
}

ol li .name {
  width: 52%;
  line-height: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
}

.detailed ol li .name {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

ol li .name span {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #F29898;
}

ol li .rating {
  width: 20%;
}

ol li .rating span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #F29898;
  opacity: .8;
}

ol li .goto {
  width: 20%;
}

ol li .goto .btn {
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 24px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

ol li .reveal {
  display: none;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
}

ol li .reveal .btn {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ol li.email {
  text-align: center;
}

ol li.email input {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-color: #F29898;
}

ol li.email button {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px auto;
  border: 2px solid #F29898;
  background-color: #F29898;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 23px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li class="toggle">
    <div class="shown">
      <div class="number">
        <span>4</span>
      </div>
      <div class="name">
        <span>GoDaddy</span>
      </div>
      <div class="rating">
        <span>8.5/10</span>
      </div>
      <div class="goto">
        <a class="btn">Visit</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reveal" id="four-reveal">
      <p>We personally love GoDaddy but <u>their are many mix reviews about the company hosting services</u>. Some love them, some don't. But GoDaddy doesn't get so big by accident, they have more than 14 million customers. We personally host our clients
        websites on GoDaddy;</p>
      <p>GoDaddy shared hosting plan offers <b>uptime of 99.9% guarantee</b>, with <b>24/7 support via phone and email or Fourm</b>; and We can tell you one thing sure, their <b>Support is the best</b>. </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I tried that too, But I want to toggle it. Means on 1st click it will show and on 2nd click it will hide. Thanks btw

Comment: Yeah and thats what the above code is doing. Did you tried?

Comment: Yeah, I already tried it. Actually, It only hiding "reveal" class when we click on the "number" class, not for whole "shown" class. Thanks :D

Comment: WOW! Work likes a charm! Thanks. .btw what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Well since its uses `position: relative`, you can't really click on the element. Hence, need to use `z-index`.